# How can I say: "I still don't speak German as well as I understand"

Tags: word-choice

Maybe I could translate it as following:

> Ich spreche noch nicht so gut Deutsch wie ich verstehe.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers. I posted a similar question on French stack exchange. They suggested me to use Google Translate and DeepL instead of posting such questions in this kind of platform. For my surprise, when I translated my French and German questions on DeepL, they matched with you guys answers and the French answers as well. I'm not sure yet, but it seems that this "DeepL" is a good translation tool.

Answer (score 2):

But you can (?) easily add "it" to your English original. And then there is the "still":

> Ich spreche **immer** noch nicht so gut Deutsch wie ich **es**
>   verstehe.

or just as well I guess:  **... noch immer ...**

Langauge names are special, but both work here the same. You leave out the article. Nobody speaks *the* English. But **it** is a language.

> Deutsche Sprache...schwere Sprache.
>
> Deutsche Sprache...**es** ist eine schwierige Sprache.

This you can translate 1:1 to English.

The position of "it/es" is different. Don't put it at the end in German! The "as/wie" makes it complicated.

> As I have told you...
>
> Wie ich dir **gesagt habe...**

Answer (score 1):

Close one!
The correct sentence would be:

> Ich spreche immer noch nicht so gut Deutsch wie ich **es** verstehe.

Comment: Faustregel: Im Deutschen im Zweifel lieber ein *es* zu viel als zu wenig ;)

Comment: genau ;) so ist es

Comment: you missed the "still" .. Ich spreche **immer noch** nicht...

Comment: Thank you ;) I edited my answer